# Doubt in potential energy of sphere on inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, potential-energy

This is not a question but a general doubt. So if a sphere is kept on an inclined plane what would be its potential energy.Will it be mgh or mg(h+r).
I need to use it in derivation (final velocity at bottom when rolling) kindly help me. thanks

[image: pls refer this]

Comment: When completely rolled down, the center of mass will still be $r$ abover the surface, so the difference in height is $h$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h$ is the height of the point of contact P of the sphere with the ramp, and the angle of the ramp is $\theta$, then
$$
V = mgh+ m\,r\cos \theta
$$
as the centre of the mass O of the ball is not directly over $x$ because PO is perpendiculr to the ramp surface.

As @Jonas has said, the $r\cos \theta$ does not change with $h$ so if your are interested only in *changes* of $V$ it is irrelevelent.